# How can I prevent heavy re-rendering when a webview(view or panel) is briefly hidden?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension.
I have to use a WebView that may take a long time to load initially.
However, when I briefly switch to a different editor from the WebView panel, it triggers a re-rendering process.

Is there any way to prevent this re-rendering?

re-render when

1. switch editor <-> webview panel
2. switch view containers(webview view)
3. [minor point] collapse and expand the webview view